# Kafka Polling Mechanism

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka messages that has been posted by the producer are keep appearing the consumer end after a specific interval

I tried to consume a message from my Kafka topic, That Time I face the issue I explained above. I suppose, it happens due to repolling after 5 mins(Which is a default poll interval) set. Is my understanding correct?

My Expected result is the message should not be reprocessed again and again. It should be processed only once. How Can I achieve that?

Comment: after poll how much time it takes to process those records more than five minutes? and also please provide the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration seems to be 
**enable.auto.commit: false and auto.commit.interval.ms: some value**

Second configuration is causing messages appearing after some specific interval(some value).
Same message is appearing at consumer end for processing because the message was not processed successfully first time.
If no last offset information available with zookeeper or broker, and  **auto.offset.reset** is set to **smallest (or earliest)** then processing will start from 0th offset.
Change **auto.offset.reset** to **largest (or latest)** if you do not want to reprocess the same message.